# How to send API Keys in Headers in Axios - React - Auth Fails

Tags: reactjs, axios

I utilize a technology that provides a REST API to users (they are a series of thermometers that wirelessly report to their server which we can query via this API or their website). Despite many attempts at trying to get connected to it utlizing React Axios I am not having any luck and want to be sure it's not my code versus their server.

Below is the only documentation on how to connect to the API:

> How to use our APIs Rest API allows users to integrate their sensor
> data into 3rd party applications. API calls can be made from
> programming language of your choice. Responses are served as either
> XML(Extensible Markup Language) or JSON (JavaScript Object Notation).
> Overuse could result in revocation of API portal.
>
> Overuse Example: making the same call more often than the data is
> updated (Datamessage Methods: 1 request per 10 minutes). Please
> utilize the webhook for real time Datamessages.
>
> *All Dates are in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time) both for the input and for the output.
> *To request a larger data load, Please contact support Authorization APIs use authorization to ensure that client requests access data
> securely. The **APIKeyID** and the **APISecretKey** both need to be included
> as headers in the posted request.
>
> Click Api Keys to get your API keys.
>
> Parameters Our parameters will need to be passed in the request as
> Param entries. The Parameter name will be set as the Key and the
> parameter value will be set as the Value.

Basically need to pass the two keys provided as headers in the axios function, which I have set up as such:

```
axios.get('https://www.providerURL.com/json/specificFunction', 
  {         
    params: 
    { 
      paramEG: 'ID here'
    }
  }, 
  {
    headers: {                
      "APISecretKey": 'secret key here',
      "APIKeyID": 'key ID here',
    }        
  }
)
```

I get this response:

```
{
"Method": "specificFunction",
"Result": "Authorization Failed"
}
```

I have confirmed the keys work using AJAX on a non-React page as a test. Additionally, they have an interactive that takes in these keys in input fields which also confirms the keys are accurate. Lastly, it took some time to get to the above snippet not delivering an error, rather, I am getting an actual response, just not the desired response.

Their support team is known to be rather slow to reply and I wanted to verify with others that the above code *seems* like it should work and if there are any suggestions as to getting their server to recognize the keys provided. I have exausted options from googling but this specific service doesn't provide many hits on google for examples.

The only other thing I don't know how to do is convert the above snip to a POST which their website infers may be what I need to be doing instead of "GET", however, I cannot for the life of me find an example POST method with keys in headers. An example of that would be absolutely amazing to confirm that their API wants only POST requests.

I thank you all very much!